# MS WORD: Can you disable tabbing to create new row in table?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to make a form with locked fields. I can't Protect the document because I still need spellcheck to be possible and I don't want to introduce macros/VBA into this if there is any way it can be avoided.

I have been using content control to lock a bunch of stuff but now run into the issue that when the user tabs from the last field in the table at the top of the document it adds a row to the table instead of tabbing to the field below the table. All my google-fu has come up blank. Is there any way to disable the adding of new rows to the table without protecting the document and therefore disabling spellcheck?

Comment: Are you giving raw file to user to input, not making forms or things like that, that make user remain in the fields that he should enter?

Comment: I would be giving the document to different users so they can fill in fields, save a copy for themselves and print it.  I am trying to avoid "Protecting" the document so that I can still use spellcheck on the document.  Protecting a document disables the ability to use spellcheck.  Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to prevent it altogether, but some way around.

**First method:**

Make a larger single cell table, 
Fix the height of its single row/ cell to "Exactly" = the size of your actual table.
Put your actual table inside this single cell table.

Now, if the person presses tab at the last cell of the inside table, the inside table will grow a row below, but that will not be visible to the person, and actually his cursor will go missing, so he will be confused or afraid that he might have broken down your design, and would eventually click outside the table and will get his cursor back. Then he will not bother doing it again.

**Second Method:**

In your actual table, you yourself create a row below the last row. 
Select this new last row and make its font size 1.
Also, Select this last row and make its height "Exactly" .01 or whatever minimum you can achieve.

Then, if the person presses tab at the last Entry cell (which will be above this new extra row created by you), the table will still create a row, and keep on creating as long as keeps on pressing tabs, but those will be so tiny that the person will not notice much difference and will eventually give up disturbing your design.

For your this newly created last row, you can even split this single miniaturized row in 100 cells or as much you can achieve, so that if he presses tabs 99 times, nothing happens, and he doesn't even see his cursor moving, so he gives up, and was able to add just one row.